# Difficult SQL-Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have 2 tables i.e. table 1 calls game and table 2 calls game_medias

structure table 1 (game)

```
-id
-genre_id
-title
-created
```

etc.

structure table 2 (game_medias)

```
-id
-game_id
-thumb
```

etc

example query:

```
select g.id,g.genre_id,g.title, gm.* 
from games g inner join game_medias as gm 
group by rand(g.id) limit 8;
```

is it possible to make a query with a extra like " where g.id = '2' " - get the genre_id from it and get into the random 8 only "items" with this genre_id ? i'm not sure if the join is the right solution - maybe someone knows a better way?

regards

Comment: Describe what you are trying to query as it may be easier to start from scratch.

Comment: Your JOIN doesn't have an ON clause.

Comment: what is a better solution in your meaning ?

Comment: don't use order by random or cache the result id externally then use php random function to do matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but I believe this will work:

```
select g.id,g.genre_id,g.title, gm.* 
from games g inner join game_medias as gm 
where (g.genre_id = (SELECT genre_id FROM games WHERE id = 2))
group by rand(g.id) limit 8;
```

If there is an index on games.id then it should be quite fast.

Comment: well this don't return any data

Comment: Thanks - i have set the index and works great a current part is:

select g.genre_id,g.title,gm.game_id,gm.media_type,gm.media_url
from games g inner join game_medias as gm
where (g.genre_id = (SELECT genre_id FROM games WHERE id = 2))
and gm.media_type = 'THUMB' and g.id=gm.game_id
group by rand(gm.game_id) limit 8;

"and g.id=gm.game_id" must be inside to get the correct values from gm. values to the correct g. values - but nice to see how fast i get the answer :)